# How to reverse an array in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

How can I print the following array in reverse order?

```
var toDoListReverse = ["Take out garbage", "Pay bills", "Cross off finished items"]
```

Comment: So exactly what is that is wrong with `reversed()`? What's the reason for this artificial restriction? `reversed()` is lazy and extremely efficient, so why not use it? Do you have some sort of homework assignment? What is your _real_ goal here? Do you need to reverse the array or do you need to enumerate the array backwards? What?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is code for swift 3

```
let array = ["IOS A", "IOS B", "IOS C"]
for item in array.reversed() {
    print("Found \(item)")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> print the array in reverse order

Like this:

```
toDoListReverse.reversed().forEach {print($0)}
```

Comment: Of course it works. I'm still scratching my head over what the original problem even was. Next time, please ask the question to which you actually want to know the answer.

Comment: @matt Hrm. I'd assumed the exercise was to do it without using `reversed()`. I may have misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 2):

Another approaches could be used as below using stride function

```
let names: [String] = ["Apple", "Microsoft", "Sony", "Lenovo", "LG"]
var reversedNames = [String]()
for arrayIndex in stride(from: names.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
    reversedNames.append(names[arrayIndex])
}
```

And using for loop as

```
let names = ["Apple", "Microsoft", "Sony", "Lenovo", "LG"]
let totalIndices = names.count - 1
var reversedNames = [String]()
for arrayIndex in 0...totalIndices {
    reversedNames.append(names[totalIndices - arrayIndex])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func reverseArray(values: [Int]) {

    var reversedArray : [Int] = []
    var lastElement : Int = -1
    for _ in values {
        lastElement += 1
    }
    for _ in values {
        reversedArray.append(values[lastElement])
        lastElement -= 1
    }
    print("reversed Array is \(reversedArray)")
}
```

You can call this function like this:

`reverseArray(values: [1, 2, 3 , 90, 9888 , 654])`

Answer (score 1):

```
 //suppose you set your array in   self.arrOfJobsList

 self.arrOfJobsList =  NSMutableArray(array: self.arrOfJobsList.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the "reversed()" method provided by the Swift.

You can use below generic code code.

```
func arrayReversal<T>(array: [T]) {

  var reverseArr = [T]()
  var count = array.count - 1

  while count >= 0 {
    reverseArr.append(array[count])
    count = count - 1
  }

  print(reverseArr)
}
```

```
var namesArray = ["Apple", "Microsoft", "Sony", "Lenovo", "Asus"]
arrayReversal(array: namesArray)

OR

let integerArray = [1,3,2,4]
arrayReversal(array: integerArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
let numbers = [10, 50, 40]

for number in numbers.reversed() {

    print(number)
}
```

// We can reverse an Array without allocating new space for its elements by calling this reversed() method.